# TCP listening socket is not created

Tags: linux, qt, sockets, network-programming, time-wait

I'm developing a Qt application and experience rather weird network issue. 
Let me show how it looks from end-user perspective.

First I start up my server and verify that it's listening on a target port:

```
[user@host server]$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 30004
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30004               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      11113/./server
```

Then I connect to the server with telnet:

```
[user@host server]$ telnet localhost 30004
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Netstat displays that connection is now established. Nothing fancy so far:

```
[user@host server]$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 30004
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30004               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      11113/./server 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:30004             127.0.0.1:34608             ESTABLISHED 11113/./server 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34608             127.0.0.1:30004             ESTABLISHED 12657/telnet
```

Then the server drops the connection based on application-specific timeout. It is set to 10 seconds at the moment:

```
[user@host server]$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 30004
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30004               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      11113/./server 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:30004             127.0.0.1:34608             TIME_WAIT   -
```

I then shut down the server and verify that the listenning socket is destroyed:

```
[user@host server]$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 30004
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:30004             127.0.0.1:34608             TIME_WAIT   -
```

Finally I start up the server again, but the listening port doesn't show up anymore:

```
[user@host server]$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 30004
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:30004             127.0.0.1:34608             TIME_WAIT   -
```

As a result client cannot connect to the server:

```
[user@host server]$ telnet localhost 30004
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm inclined to think that this is a configuration issue, not a bug in the application. 
This scenario seems to work on my laptop's Ubuntu. The aforementioned output was produced on linux box as well.

UPDATE: One more thing that is different in these two environemnt is qt version. On my notebook I have 4.8.6, on linux box it's 4.6.2. Not sure if it matters.

Comment: What error do your code report when you try to bind/listen/accept your server socket ? Is there any difference if you set the SO_REUSEADDR socket option on your server socket (same as using [QAbstractSocket::ShareAddress](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QAbstractSocket.html) as the BindMode if you're using Qt sockets )? Is your server listening on anything (run netstat -apn |grep server)

Comment: @nos, 
I'm using QTcpServer and all I can see is that call to the listen method returns false. 
How can I enable this option for QTcpServer? Afaik QTcpServer sets this option automagically.
Nope, nothing:
[user@host server]$ sudo netstat -anp | grep server 
Active Internet connections (servers and established) 
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)

Comment: It seems to be the default on *nix. So if listen() returns false, call QAbstractSocket::SocketError and see what it says. You should probably post your code anyway.

Comment: Thanks, it reports 8, i.e. QAbstractSocket::AddressInUseError...

Comment: How it's possible that QTcpServer::listen yields AddressInUseError although it sets SO_REUSEADDR option?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was an issue with versions of qt libraries. We upgraded it to latest 4.x.x and now the problem seems to be resolved.